# How do I create a text file on server or memory?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I create a text file and write the contents of a string to it? I plan to reference to the text file later. It could be on the server (root folder) or anywhere where I can reference it. Below is the string contents

```
 foreach (string s in strValuesToSearch)
            {

                if (result.Contains(s))

                    result = result.Replace(s, stringToReplace);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx) method:

```
string result = "foo bar";
File.WriteAllText(@"c:\foo.txt", result);
```

Comment: How do I reference the web folder location?

Comment: If you are in the context of an ASPX page you can use `Server.MapPath("~/Folder"")`

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have proper permission to write on the server you can take advantage of the methods of the [`System.IO.File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3saad2h5.aspx) class

[`System.IO.File.WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext.aspx)